# Telnet connection refused

Tags: centos, telnet

ok brand new install of Centos 6, updated, selinux off, xinetd installed, telnet server installed, both running. Made sure it was explcitly disalbed=no in xinet telnet config, I still get

```
        telnet localhost
       Trying ::1...
       telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused

        telnet localhost 25
       Trying ::1...
       telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
```

I am trying to test postfix, and I've been told to use telnet to do it. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't solve the telnet issue, but I found that the mail command is probably the best solution for this. easy to use and change:

echo “This will go into the body of the mail.” | mail -s “Hello world” you@youremailid.com

This allows test emails to be sent, and bypasses telnet.

Answer (score 0):

Try using SSH: `man ssh`
Use PuTTY as a client:  http://www.putty.org/
http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Answer (score 0):

Don'ts:

- You don't need a telnet server on CentOS to test Postfix via telnet.
- You don't need to disable SELinux.
- You don't need xinetd.

Do's:

- Install a telnet client on your client machine (if using Windows, take PuTTY).
- Ensure that Postfix on CentOS is bound to your primary or to all IP address(es).
- Open Port 25 in iptables.
- Telnet from your client and talk SMTP: `telnet ip-of-server 25`